# Suggestions on Setting up Development Environment

Tags: development-environment, production-environment

After referring to many posts, opinions and feedback from SO, I have just bought a [Lenovo Thinkpad T410](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/notebooks/thinkpad/t-series/t410) . x64 Win 7 Prof, 500 GB @ 7200 RPM , Core i7 620M processor, 4GB DDR3 RAM.

I am now setting up my development environment on the new machine. I need your suggestions in setting up a clean, structured and risk-free Development Environment.

Something about what I intend to do on this machine:

- I am Entrepreneur bootstrapping my Startup. So I will have business related purposes (presentations) other than Coding.
- I do coding on Microsoft stack currently for some of my other projects. But will start coding in other technologies such as RoR. So I need to have MS products (VS, IIS) and other OSS'
- This machine also doubles up as production environment on top of Development Environment.
- I don't have a separate Desktop for doing heavy lifting. This is my whole and sole workstation.

I have read a lot about VMwares here and how they help to keep the machine clean and ordered which you can just wipe out clean and have reinstalled as you wish. Is it a good thing to have VMs each for Microsoft stact, RoR stact and so on or have all of them installed on my main machine itself.

Also, apart from this, it would be great if someone can suggest some good options for Firewall+Antivirus+Malware stack (considering that this is a Win 7 machine)

ThanQ

Answer (score 3):

> This machine also doubles up as
>   production environment on top of
>   Development Environment.

You are setting yourself up for a world of hurt.

Aside from that, it is just common sense that you should use some form of VCS (I recommend Git) and store all your code NOT on your development machine.  You should be able to checkout out your code, run a script, and be up and running.  You are bootstrapping  a startup; pay the $12/month to keep your code safe.

VMs are a good idea if you need to support different environments, for example Win7, Win Vista, and perhaps some flavor of linux.  If you take my suggestion and use a remote VCS setup, you can checkout from the remote source onto your VMs.

Another benefit of VMs is you can set up a base install, with all the software you need, and create an image of it, so from that point on you can pass the image around, and you won't need to install the baseline software again.

Comment: Yeah, I do plan to have a Version Control. Git or SVN depending on the project. I was primarily concerned about how to install all the required softwares on the single machine - Visual Studi, Eclipse, IIS, Apache, SQL Server etc.